# Is Freebase a key-value store?

Tags: distributed, freebase, key-value-store

How does freebase storage system works? Does it use a type of distributed key value store like Cassandra or MongoDB? I have been looking for documentation regarding the details of this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freebase uses a proprietary [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) called Graphd to store the types, attributes, topics, etc.